# Search for a word in FAT with QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, query

Using QGIS 3.10 I need to select all points that have the word *fium* and its variace like *fiume*, *fiumara*, *FIUME*, etc.
The name of field is toponimo, I've used this query:

> "toponimo"  = '%fium%'

But I've zero results and this is not correct because I see a lot of rows that have this information.

What is the right way to solve my problem?

Comment: Have you tried `"toponimo" Like '%fium%'`?

Comment: regex is also an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right expression should `"toponimo" Like '%fium%'` for searching using wildcard. You can refer to the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html) for more information.  If you want to search for wildcard using case sensitive, you need to use `Ilike`.